# Azure Resource Manager Site-to-site VPN Data In 0B

Tags: azure

I have a few questions regarding establishing Site-to-Site VPN connection to my local network and Azure Virtual Network (Resource Manager)

To begin, I'll give you some context. I had an environment before (classic), and it was working just fine. I decided to migrate everything to Resource Manager; the connection is up, but my local network is not sending data to Azure network.

The only thing I changed in my previous VPN is the IP address on Phase 1 settings. I used the same shared key.

The status is up, but the incoming data to the virtual network is 0B. Am I missing something?

Cheers

Comment: firewall on your end probably or route configuration mistakes. Did you change the VNet IP address segment in Azure? I´ve seen similar issues in the past and they were all related to firewall blocking the connection between the local network and azure vnet (outbound) or route not properly propagated/configured, that is, although connected, the local network doesn't know how to reach Azure VNet.

Comment: Yes, I've double-checked (millionth checked) my routeing, and everything looks to me how they're supposed to be. My VNet has 3 subnets, 172.x.100.0/27, 10.x.100.0/27, and the gateway 10.x.100.32/28. I have a 'Connection' from my VNet and Local Network (double checked my Public IP).
In my firewall, The VPN is pointing to the VNet Gateway Public IP. Encryption and Authentication on my Phase 1 and Phase 2 are identical. 
I have 2 policies, Local ([Local Subnet]) --> VNet (172.x100.0/27 ) and VNet (172.x.100.0/27) --> Local ([Local Subnet]).